# Add JWT Bearer Authentication in Server Side Blazor (3.0.0-preview.6)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor, asp.net-authentication, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to add JWT Bearer authentication using Azure B2C. I'm using the default project template for creating Blazor Server Side application with Authentication. I chose B2C authentication at the creation page, which sets the default authentication using

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureADB2C(o => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", o));
```

This works well.

I'm trying to add JWT Bearer authentication instead. This is the code I'm using:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureADB2CBearer(o => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", o));
```

Additionally, I added `"ClientId": "my_client_id"` to the configuration section since it's required by the scheme and this code here points it's used when using this scheme
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/a784f4575b738ec5b7c6f5cfff2b1fee10de5118/src/Azure/AzureAD/Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI/src/AzureADB2CJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.cs#L32

However, when trying to Login I get error `Sorry, there's nothing at this address.`

This suggests that the built-in controller isn't getting hit (link below).

I also tried modifying the login link from `/AzureADB2C/Account/SignIn` to `/AzureADB2C/Account/SignIn/AzureADB2CJwtBearer`, but I got the same result.
The code here suggests the scheme name should get passed to the controller method, which is why I did that, but still same issue.
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/a784f4575b738ec5b7c6f5cfff2b1fee10de5118/src/Azure/AzureAD/Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI/src/Areas/AzureADB2C/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L26

I understand Authentication was added just recently and this is still experimental and looking at the code it looks like JWT should be supported, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this? I have the same issue trying to get the access token for the user to do an on behalf call to a webapi.

Comment: No, still using the default Cookie auth. I believe adding JWT can be accomplished by passing it to signalR `accessTokenFactory` to the blazor Hub. The server side should be able to validate it properly. At least this is what I would try first.

Comment: Any chance you could share the code that worked for you?  I'm not getting this to work at all.  Need to get a id/access token from B2C but nothing I try is working.

Comment: Honestly, I just used the default template project with Authentication inside VS and replaced the values to my B2C tenant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for server-side blazor.net with AAD B2C you can simply use the project creation template for server-side blazor and make two changes to point to your AAD B2C Idenity Provider instead of the the Azure Active Directory (AAD) one that is created by the template.

**Change 1:** appsettings.json, replace the AzureAd something like this:

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
"Instance": "https://myaadb2ctenantname.b2clogin.com/tfp/",
"ClientId": "a4444-83b0-4752-4444-33d7a7323457",
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
"Domain": "myaadb2ctenantname.onmicrosoft.com",
"SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_MySignInV2Policy",
"ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_V2SSPR",
"EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_V2SiPe"
```

},

**Change 2:** in Startup.cs, replace the services.AddAuthentication line for AzureAd with something like:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
```

Those are the only changes required assuming you have setup your AAD B2C according to best-practice shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-tutorials-web-app?tabs=applications

Comment: Since I posted this question, support has been updated. There's now `AddAzureADB2CBearer` extension method available with actual support or this scheme, which wasn't there before.
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/1fe7f5e02aff5e16cf04246839a086584747ea08/src/Azure/AzureAD/Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI/src/AzureAdB2CAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs#L33